# Why no AtomicBooleanFieldUpdater in java?

Tags: java, atomic

There are `Atomic*FieldUpdater` classes in `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package, like:

- `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater`
- `AtomicLongFieldUpdater`
- `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` etc.

But why no `AtomicBooleanFieldUpdater`?

Answer (score 1):

The only meaningful method that such an updater could possibly have is a basic CAS job. A method that does:

- If the value is `false`, set it to `true`, and return `false`. If the value is `true`, then it stays `true`, and this returns `true`. And do this all atomically. (It's: set to true, then return the old value, atomically).

And that's.. the only method that seems relevant here. Those `get()` methods in these Updater classes are just for convenience; they don't give you any more atomicity than just `thatThing.fieldName`; would get you.

There is no point to compareAndSet - the above is identical to it (*IF* the field is currently `false`, set it to `true`, and return `true` to indicate the CAS job updated. If it is already `true`, then don't change it, and return `false` - that is *identical* to the negation of the above method - walk through all the cases if you're having a hard time seeing how that works).

The only other method this class could have that isn't covered by the above and isn't the just-for-convenience `get()` is, I guess, `lazySet`.

It would be useful perhaps, but only slightly so.

One crazy solution would be to just let `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater` work for boolean fields as well - they are really just full-word-size in all JVM impls I know of. I checked: The API won't let you do that (throws an error if you attempt to create a new AIFU for a boolean field).